# Use texreg::wordreg within whole markdown knitted Word document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to use texreg::wordreg within a Markdown file with several other calculations that I want to finally knit to an MS Word file. However, the function demands that I enter a file name and hence export each table separately. Is there a workaround that I could use so I don't need extra files for each table? I already tried "file = NULL" but it doesn't work (Error: "'file' must be a valid file path.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of wordreg.

Try

```
texreg::knitreg(your_list_of_models, center = FALSE)
```

It should automatically adapt your texreg table based on the type of document that you are knitting.